# Want to install a new font in MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex

I am using MiKTeX in PC with WinEDT 6.0 version. I want to use a new Type1 font for one of my document and I have `*.afm` and `*.PFB` files with me. How can I install a font newly and what are the map files need to be updated for that. Please guide me step by step.

Comment: Please tell us the name of the font. Do you use pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Comment: I’d love to help, but the name and better a link, where to get, would really help. Note, that here on TeX.SX you already could find useful hints anyway.

Comment: After re-reading: Is there really no map file included? This will make things harder.